# Создание движущегося фона

Tags: c#

Я бы хотел сделать меняющийся фон для игры гонки. Есть три машины движущиеся по оси y с рандомной скоростью. Фон должен двигаться по мере движения объектов(машин). Важно чтобы фон не заканчивался и находился в постоянном движении. Вопрос: как такое реализовать?
Буду премного благодарен! [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вы сами пробовали решить свою задачу и что не получилось?

Comment: режете фон на N горизонтальных полосок и зацикливаете рисование `i = (i + 1)%N`

Comment: Если фон меняющийся, то генерить новые куски фона по мере необходимости